# how to add an info window on kml layer in a google map using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add an info window on a kml layer in a google map, It should be display when mouseover on a country. I tried to add info window but it was not successful I can add info window any point of google map and on a marker, but I need to add an info window on a kml layer when mouseover on a country.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to you kmllayer. Add an event listener to call a function that either creates a message box or call an existing message box.

```
kmlLayer.addListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
  var text = 'Some Text';
  showInContentWindow(text);
});

function showInContentWindow(text) {
    // create or call an existing window
  var sidediv = document.getElementById('content-window');
  sidediv.innerHTML = text;
}
```